# Added bin directory to my path, can't execute commands in it with 'sudo command'

Tags: root, path, bashrc

I made a `bin` directory in my home folder where I place all my scripts. Then in my .bashrc I added the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/myusername/bin
```

So I could access files I placed in there from anywhere. But some of the scripts need to be executed as root. So I thought, I could symlink my .bashrc as root, (as in /root/.bashrc points to /home/myusername/.bashrc, don't know if this is smart) so when I need to run a script as root I can just do:

```
sudo program_that_requires_root
```

But then I get a:

```
sudo: program_that_requires_root: command not found
```

If I login as root and execute the program, it works fine though. So what is the correct way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: My guess: `sudo` probably is using `secure_path` instead of your `$PATH`.  Run `sudo -V` as root (e.g. `sudo sudo -V`) and look for lines that contain `PATH`.

Comment: Yes, at least in Debian, open the file `/etc/sudoers` and find this line: `Defaults secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` (paths may vary) - if you add your user `bin` path, it'll work. (Perhaps that solution is not recommended for other reasons; I don't know.) Oh, in the file mentioned, it says you shouldn't change it, but I did, and it works great, at least in terms of what I tried to achieve (having the same problem as you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make sure these two lines are present in the sudoers file.

```
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:$
```

See these URLs for more details:

- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639841
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sudo-aptitude-problem-905784/

Comment: I guess `$` at the end of the second (code) line followed when you copied - it should be a closing quote, of course. Also, the **new** path to the user binaries (and other executables, as @Carlito mentioned scripts) must be added. (You probably did this; just got chopped off.)

Comment: Thanks, I looked in the sudoers file and added my path to the second line, works great!

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` resets the `PATH` environment variable to a built-in or administrator-supplied default, in most configurations. So you won't be able to just type `sudo myscript`.

You could write a wrapper function:

```
sudo () {
  local cmd
  case $1 in
    -*) :;; # there are options, change nothing
    */*) :;; # explicit path, change nothing
    *) # a command name, look it up in our $PATH
      cmd=$(type -p -- "$1")
      if [[ -n $cmd ]]; then shift; set -- "$c" "$@"; fi;;
  esac
  command sudo "$@"
}
```

(This is for bash; change `type -P` to `type -p` in ksh or zsh.)

Comment: Hm, though I don't doubt this does it, it seems a bit complicated - is there if fact some hidden gain, compared to editing `/etc/sudoers`, which seems a much simpler solution?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg If this is your computer, you can edit the `sudoers` file and change `secure_path`. If this is a shared machine, the admin is unlikely to be willing to accommodate you: a user-chosen `secure_path` setting, or recompiling sudo without that option, would be a maintenance headache.

Answer (score 0):

By default sudo resets the environment.  Have you tried adding the path to root's .bashrc?  Or invoke sudo with -E (which only works if setenv in sudoers is set, or the respective command has the SETENV tag set).

Comment: Changing root's `.bashrc` won't help: `sudo` doesn't start an interactive instance of bash here.